# Can you buy an annuity before age 55 in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, retirement, law, annuity, early-retirement

I wish to retire young. To estimate how much I would need, I have hunted around the internet for any way to estimate how much an annuity paying £30,000 a year would cost for a 40-year-old man with no health conditions. I thought this would be simple, but every resource I've found enforced a minimum age of 55.

Is there any law that prevents buying an annuity before the age of 55?

Comment: There is less point to buying an annuity when you are younger, because there is less risk. Someone who is 60 expects to live 25 years, but might live 40, i.e. 60% longer. Someone who is 40 expects to live 45, but might live 60 i.e. 33% longer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are probably two issues you are running into here:

- Lack of demand meaning the products aren't worth offering. Even allowing a lower age on an existing product means more work to figure out mortality rates etc.
- The laws around when you can withdraw money from your tax-advantaged pension savings. This is 55 or above in almost all cases where you might want to buy an annuity. Most annuities are designed to be bought with pension savings so that you pay tax on everything the annuity pays out, in exchange for having had tax relief when you saved into the pension.

There is a thing called a "purchased life annuity", which you can buy with already-taxed savings, and you will only get taxed on the parts of the payout that relate to investment growth. A quick search finds one provider (Canada Life) that advertise them as being available from age 35, but you have to go through a financial advisor to actually get more information like a quote.

Comment: Got a link for the Canada Life thing? If you can prove that they offer it, then that is certainly an answer.

Comment: https://www.canadalife.co.uk/retirement/purchased-life-annuity/ - I hesitated about including it in the answer as it might rot over time and I don't really want to explicitly advertise them.